# Triangle Inequality on complex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, triangles

#### Problem

Let $z= x + iy$, then prove that:

$$|x| + |y| \le   2 ^{1/2} |z|$$

#### Progress

I've tried to write $|z|$ as $(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}$, and to make some algebra after this, but I'm really new at proving things, I just get to nothing.

Comment: Well, I am really new at math, so I've tried to write |z| as (x^2 + y^2)^1/2, and to make some algebra after this, but I'm really new at proving things, I just get to nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: 1) First square both sides.

2) Write $|z|^2=x^2+y^2$.

3) "Bring the RHS to the LHS": That is- rearrange the inequality in the form $LHS-RHS \geq 0$.

4) Now do an obvious "completing the square" argument and use the fact that the square of any real number is $\geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks, bro. It helped a lot. I just didn't see the "completing the square".

Comment: @marco: and yet you accepted the more cryptic answer ;-).

Comment: Man, I'm just new at this, don't know what I'm really doing when clicking here.

Comment: :) no issues @marco. All the best, and happy exploring both math and this site.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Since both sides are positive, the inequality is equivalent to
$$(|x|+|y|)^2\le2(|x|^2+|y|^2)\ .$$
See if you can simplify this and hence prove that it is always true.

Answer (score 0):

If $z=\Re z+i\Im z$ then not only this one but also you can prove that,
$$|\Re z|,|\Im z|≤|z|$$
$$2|\Re z||\Im z|≤|z|^2$$
$$|z|≤|\Re z|+|\Im z|≤√2 |z|$$
All of these are just algebraic manipulations of $(x-y)^2≥0;$ $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}.$